# Warning on loading XML data

Tags: php

I am using following code to get current time (hours) in Los Angeles

```
$response_xml_data = file_get_contents('http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/34.05223/-118.24368');
$data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
$dt = new DateTime($data->localtime);
$time = $dt->format('H:i:s');
list($hour, $min, $sec) = explode(':', $time);
echo $hour;
```

This code is working fine offline, but i am getting following warning message when i put this file online:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in [PHP file name and line number]
```

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/34.05223/-118.24368)`
   `[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be 
    found in [PHP file name and line number]`

It looks like i am using a wrong method to read XML data, please suggest?

Comment: Please read the error message. "URL file-access is disabled" clearly states that your webspace provider has blocked that feature in the server configuration.

Comment: Is there any alternate method available in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that on the server you call "online" the [HTTP wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) is disabled for file functions in PHP.

Comment: Can you please suggest any alternate method?

Comment: If you don't have control over to server to enable the HTTP wrapper, you can use alternative ways provided by PHP's stream functions http://uk1.php.net/stream to create HTTP request from within PHP code OR an external tool like CURL http://curl.haxx.se/ which has PHP extension..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by having php's `allow_url_fopen` setting disabled on your server. This prevents the https wrapper from being available, or something like that.

You can enable `allow_url_fopen` in your **php.ini** file and this should error should go away. Not sure of other repercussions of this so know what you are changing before you change it.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to override php default configuration open `php.ini`

`allow_url_fopen = ON`